# php sum column in multiple tables and return as one total

Tags: php

I have a php code below that sum up the column going through multiple tables and return 3 separate total amounts after the query is done since I have 3 tables. If I want to sum up those 3 total amounts into one, in what ways do I need to change the code to accomplish that?

```
foreach($result as $row) {
  $stmt1 = $DB_CON_C->prepare("SELECT SUM(total_fee) AS total_amount FROM `".$row['files']."`");
  $stmt1->execute();
  $sum1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo $sum1['total_amount'];
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to attacks. The advantage of using prepare statement is so that you can bindParams

Comment: If not in SQL, you could just add up `$sum1`in PHP.

Comment: @FrenchMajesty - You can't bind column names (which the OP is inserting) using prepared statements. The column names should never be injected using user inputs, though. There are safer ways to do it, like having a "white list" of column names that are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$totalAmount = 0;

foreach($result as $row) {
    $stmt1 = $DB_CON_C->prepare("SELECT SUM(total_fee) AS total_amount FROM `".$row['files']."`");
    $stmt1->execute();

    $sum1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  totalAmount += $sum1['total_amount'];
}

echo $totalAmount;
```

Just create a variable outside of the loop's scoop and add up to it.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly when added the missing $ before totalAmount.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Create a variable outside the loop, then increment it per loop.

```
$grandTotal = 0;
foreach($result as $row) {
  $stmt1 = $DB_CON_C->prepare("SELECT SUM(total_fee) AS total_amount FROM `".$row['files']."`");
  $stmt1->execute();
  $sum1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $grandTotal = $grandTotal +  $sum1['total_amount'];
}
echo $grandTotal;
```

Not sure if this works, but you get the idea.